# All fields are not showing for Group and Sort Section

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-7

I have a report created in `Crystal Report 7`.
I have modified a view on which the report depends.
When I clicked `Verify Database` new fields are added in `Field's list`.
After modification of View now I need to change the Grouping Order of report. When I searched in Fields Explorer there were all the fields present, but in Group Box those fields are not coming. Am I missing something, please help.

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

Also In `Visual Linking Expert` tab `Browse Field` is disable and for rest are enable.
[image]

Comment: are the missing fields of a specific type, like nvarchar or similar? Grouping might not apply to some kinds of fields.

Comment: missing fields are varchar, but few of them are coming in list. Like ChequNo, Amt

Comment: This is probably a result of the field's length (>2000 characters) or its type (BLOB).

Comment: Actually the View from which data coming was combination of Three `unions`. `ReturnReason` column in Union was having different size. May be because of this it was not enabled.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have never worked with CR 7 but I suspect a field type/size/characteristics issue. Can you put these 'missing' fields in your detail section and have a look at the displayed values? If these look normal, what I would try are the following:

- convert the missing fields into 'smaller' ones,  by setting them in
  the query the following way, just to check if the problem is linked to a field size
  issue or something like that.

  CONVERT(varchar(10), returnReason) as returnReason
- Another try would be to create the grouping fields in the report, adding corresponding Formula Fields like

  groupReturnreason = left(returnReason, 10)

No guarantee of course, just a trial.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I was waiting for some steps. I will check and reply back. Thanks once again.

Comment: First point `CONVERT(varchar(10), returnReason) as returnReason` solved the issue.

Comment: crystal reports can be sometimes quite puzzling!